# Write an algorithm that finds the second smallest value among a, b, and c

Tags: algorithm

How do I find the second smallest value among a,b and c in Java?

```
Find-2nd-Smallest (n: array)  
  smallest : infinity  
  2nd-smallest : infinity  
  for each i in n    
    if i < smallest      
      2nd-smallest = smallest      
      smallest = i    
    else if i < 2nd-smallest      
      2nd-smallest = i  
  return 2nd-smallest
```

How would I make it work for (a,b,c)? I am very confused on how to get a value with only 3 letters.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to know the industry term for a thing. Research *order statistics algorithms* in Google.

Comment: `Find-2nd-Smallest([a,b,c])`? Or do you want a `Find-3nd-Smallest` function? Or doesn't the provided function work (if not, what's wrong with it?)?

Comment: Probably something that you can do recursively where the next smallest number is nothing, then you use the tail.

Comment: @Dukeling
3nd? you say?

Comment: That's the 2st most funny comment I've seen this week :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? What is confusing?

Comment: @DanzaiVer I blame sleep deprivation.

Answer (score 2):

The function in this pseudo-code you gave finds the smallest and second smallest values in an array.

Run it on the array {a,b,c}.

Comment: @JimMischel The asker gave pseudo-code for a method in the question. The question appeared to be how to make the method work on three values.

Comment: I see. I misread your response. I tried to remove my downvote, but was told that it's "locked in" and can't be changed unless you edit your response. If you make a small change to your answer (it can be anything), I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Maybe he meant to write it using only three variables. Not important. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only three values, you can get away with a very simple function (pseudo-code below):

```
def second_smallest (a,b,c):
    if a < b:
        if b < c:
            return b
        return c
    if a < c:
        return a
    return c
```

Obviously that will become massively unwieldy if there are more than three numbers but, *at that point* (see YAGNI), you would convert it to a more generalised solution.

That would be along the lines of:

```
def second_smallest (list):
    if list.size < 2:
        throw error "not enough numbers"
    if list[0] < list[1]:
        first = list[0]
        second = list[1]
    else:
        first = list[1]
        second = list[0]
    for each index 2 through list.size - 1 inclusive:
        if list[index] < first:
            second = first
            first = list[index]
            next for
        if list[index] < second:
            second = list[index]
    return second
```

That's *basically* the same sort of logic in your question but with some pre-checks to avoid having to represent infinity (that would be okay if your types were floating point but not so useful for integers).

You should be aware that the generalised solution also solves the more specific problem, assuming your three integers are actually in a list structure of some sort. If you just have the three "naked" values and you're not specifically tasked with coping with the generalised case, I'd use the first block of pseudo-code above.